# Colocar divs secundarias ao lado umas das outras dentro da principal

Tags: html, css

Bom é o seguinte, tenho o seguinte código, o que pretendo é colocar as divs que estão dentro da div com id="goncalo" ao lado umas das outras em forma de linha reta, ou seja, quero que fique alinhadas em forma duma "reta".

```
<div id="goncalo">
<div class="preview-wrapper" style="background-image: url('1.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; width:50px; height:100px; background-size:100%;" data-id="24294275">
</div>
<div class="preview-wrapper" style="background-image: url('2.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; width:100px; height:100px; background-size:100%;">
</div>


            </div>
```

Comment: Mas tem que ficar equalizada a altura das duas imagens ?

Comment: Exato. Tudo igual ao lado uma da outra.

Comment: Adiciona no CSS a seguinte linha: #goncalo > div { float:left;}

Comment: Não resulta! Já tentei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.
Atualmente esta coisa do posicionamento em CSS está bastante facilitado.

```
.goncalo {
   width: 100%; //o tamanho que quiseres
   text-align: justify;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
 }
.preview-wrapper {
   width: 100px;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

And so on!
Reparei que tens widths diferentes para as .preview-wrapper!

Bom, a questão aqui é utilizares as [FLEXBOXES](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Abraço e bom trabalho.

Comment: As divs estão alinhadas na mesma linha, mas estão mesmo longe uma da outra, vou deixar abaixo um print.

Comment: http://prnt.sc/e20ul1

Comment: Já entendi, foi do 100% existe alguma forma de calcular automaticamente consoante o tamanho das imagens? das divs colocadas?

Comment: O tamanho das imagens varia? Então usa auto para a width da .preview-wrapper... Mas seria mais fácil se mostrasses o layout do que pretendes. Pela imagem que colocaste é difícil, para mim pelo menos, orientar-te.

Comment: Já consegui o que pretendia, mas tive que colocar a largura da div goncalo a 0.